# Typescript error: Property '#interval' does not exist on type 'Partial<Observer<number>> | ((value: number) => void)'.(2339)

Tags: javascript, typescript, function

I'm trying out rxjs with JS classes in Angular and I'm getting the error depicted in the title when I'm trying to access the #interval property inside the error function.

```js
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
      #firstObsSubscription: Subscription;
      #interval?: number;
    
      constructor() {
        const customIntervalObservable = new Observable<number>((observer) => {
          let count = 0;
          this.#interval = setInterval(() => {
            console.log('En setInterval', count);
            observer.next(count++);
    
            if (count > 3) {
              observer.error(new Error('Count is greater than 3'));
              observer.next(100);
              observer.complete();
            }
    
          }, 1_000);
        });
    
        this.#firstObsSubscription = customIntervalObservable.subscribe({
          next(data) {
            console.log('En subscribe', data);
          },
          error(err) {
              if (this.#interval)  // <-- I'm getting the error here
                   clearInterval(this.#interval);
              console.log('En error', err);
          },
          complete() {
            console.log('En complete');
          },
        });
      }
    
      ngOnInit() {}
    
      ngOnDestroy(): void {
        console.log('Destroying HomeComponent...');
        this.#firstObsSubscription.unsubscribe();
    
        if (this.#interval) clearInterval(this.#interval);
      }
}
```

I tried writing the function outside the object literal and then pass it into the object literal, but it is an awful solution:

```js
let errorFn = (err: any) => {
    if (this.#interval) 
        clearInterval(this.#interval);
    console.log('En error', err);
};

this.#firstObsSubscription = customIntervalObservable.subscribe({
      next(data) {
        console.log('En subscribe', data);
      },
      error: errorFn // <- passing the function object here works! but it is awful
});
```

I tried also using the bind function but I get a different error from TS:
[image]

Could someone help me out here with a nicer solution to my problem? Or telling me how could I google my problem, since I don't know how it's my problem called?

Here is a stackblitz reproducing the error: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ttb1zo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts

Comment: Use an arrow function... `error: (err) => { ... }`. _TL;DR_ the short form object method `error(err) { ... }` is equivalent to `error: function (err) { ... }`